# New bie : Why is this code not able to read anything from the firebase database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

The Following is my main activity, in another activity the user can login and upload audio files to the firebase storage; after that it saves the link and the current date time in the firebase database in reverse order.
The structure of the database is Audios> Feb 26,2018> "http:// link to firebase storage"
What I am trying to achieve in this activity is to read the link from the database> Store the value in the string value> and play it on mediaplayer but the following code is not able to read the link from the database for the life of me Please help me I am a new bie

```
package com.shresthawebworks.dailydevotional;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{
private MediaPlayer mMediaplayer;
private ImageButton dplayButton;
private ImageButton dpauseButton;
private ImageButton dstopButton;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;
private TextView durl;
private TextView drealurl;

private String currentDateTimeString =         DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
private static final String TAG = null;
private String value = "Udated";
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dplayButton = findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    dpauseButton = findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
    dstopButton = findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    durl = findViewById(R.id.dateString);
    drealurl = findViewById(R.id.urlText);

    handler = new Handler();
    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

    mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Audios");

    // Read from the database
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            value = (String)    dataSnapshot.child(currentDateTimeString).getValue();
            // do your stuff here with value

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
   fetchAudioUrlFromFirebase();
//.setDataSource();
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new  SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean input) {
        if (input){
            mMediaplayer.seekTo(progress);
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

    });

    configureNextButton();}
    public void playCycle(){
    seekBar.setProgress(mMediaplayer.getCurrentPosition());
    if (mMediaplayer.isPlaying()){
        runnable =new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            playCycle();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
    }
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


   // mMediaplayer.resu;
    playCycle();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMediaplayer.pause();
    playCycle();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
   mMediaplayer.release();
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}





private void fetchAudioUrlFromFirebase() {
    final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    durl.setText(currentDateTimeString);
    drealurl.setText(value);

    // Create a storage reference from our app
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dailydevotional-9f982.appspot.com/o/audios%2Ftwoprincess.mp3?alt=media&token=e3f98223-68e8-461a-8452-54eca96af4fd");
    storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            try {
                // Download url of file
                final String url = uri.toString();
                mMediaplayer.setDataSource(url);
                // wait for media player to get prepare
                mMediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(MainActivity.this);
                mMediaplayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i("TAG", e.getMessage());
                }
            });

}
@Override
public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {

    dplayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());




            mp.start();
            playCycle();

        }
    });
    dpauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.pause();
        }
    });
    dstopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playCycle();
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
            //fetchAudioUrlFromFirebase();

        }
    });
}


private void configureNextButton(){

    ImageButton dButton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.starLogin);
    dButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UploadActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: There is a bit to much code to go through. Please limit it to only the relevant code. (for example all the mediaplayer code can go if this is about getting data from firebase)

Comment: @AndréKool Thank you for your response unfortunately I am not able to edit the post my database code is in the oncreate() function. Thank you one again

Comment: My first quess would be you are trying to get the audio file before you finished getting the link to it (basic asynchronous behaviour).

Comment: The audio file is already stored in the Firebase Storage and the link to it is stored in the database. I am trying to store the link in the variable "value" by reading from the database, and then play the link using the variable I just read from the database, but the problem is that it is not reading from the database. I analysing I found that the line             value = (String)    dataSnapshot.child(currentDateTimeString).getValue(); is not executing

Comment: You should add some console messages to your code to test if and most importantly **when** everything executes. Make sure they are in the right place, in the function you want to test and not right after it.